# How to fetch count of attachments (only) in graph api using java

Tags: java, email, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments

I want to fetch count of attachments in a mail using grapgClient in java.
One way is there is fetch AttachmentCollectionPage and then get number. But I want to get count attachment count while I am fetching subject, received. I do not want to download content of attachments.

So do we have any way to call like this:

```
graphClientService.messages(messageId)
                 .buildRequest()
                    .select("subject,receivedDatetime,isRead,attachments.count")
                            .get();
```

Do we have any way to fetch count like this ***attachments.count*** ?

Answer (score 0):

One way can be this

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{messageId}/attachments/$count
```

Code

```
int attachmentsCount = graphClient.me().messages(messageId).attachments().count()
.buildRequest()
.get();
```

The correct way based on ODATA should be

```
Message message = graphClient.me().messages(messageId)
.buildRequest()
.expand("attachments($count=true)")
.select("id,subject,receivedDatetime,isRead")
.get();
```

In `$expand` you should be able specify query parameter for expanded properties but Graph API ignores it

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your quick response.
I do not want to call separate api like above.
I want to fetch count number during fetching subject,time etc

Comment: @Afsar The correct query Message message = graphClient.me().messages(messageId)
 .buildRequest()
 .expand("attachments($count=true;$top=0)")
 .select("id,subject,receivedDatetime,isRead")
 .get(); doesn't return number of attachments. Query parameters inside expand are ignored by Graph API.

Comment: what would be the equivalent version fo this for getting the last say 10 most recent files on onedrive? there is very little documentation on DrivesRequestBuilder